# How to remove the vertical white line between the two green divs without floating?

Tags: css

How to remove the vertical white line between the two green divs without floating them?

JSFIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/ZdS48/

HTML

```
<div class="left">TODO write content1</div>
<div class="left">TODO write content2</div>
<div >TODO write content3</div>
<div>TODO write content4</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
}

div.left {
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:inline-block;
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: i dont see a white line latest FF on mac osx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That white line is a space character that is placed between the divs.

```
<div class="left">TODO write content1</div> <--This new line is considered a space-->
<div class="left">TODO write content2</div>
```

Remove it and it works.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdS48/1/)

---

You can also fix it by setting the body font-size to 0 and the font-size of the div to whatever it should be:

```
body
{
    font-size: 0;
}

div{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdS48/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the actual space, in this case the line break, between the two divs in your HTML markup

```
<div class="left">TODO write content1</div><div class="left">TODO write content2</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="left">TODO write content1</div>
<div class="left">TODO write content2</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uYMaA/

Answer (score 0):

give margin-left to set the position of the div 
here:

div.left {    margin-left:-3.5;}